# Trying to transpose and create pivot in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, pivot, transpose, unpivot

I am struggling with unpivot and pivot commands, but cannot quite get it right.
I want to transpose using Transact SQL from table 1 to table 2:

[click here to see my source and destination tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqkas.jpg)

How can I accomplish this? So far I got to this:

```
SELECT  CASE RIGHT(name, 1) WHEN  'R' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(6), Q) + 'R' 
                            WHEN  'D' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(6), Q) + 'D' 
                            ELSE           CONVERT(nvarchar(6), Q) + 'A' END AS Q1, 
                            value, name
FROM    (SELECT Q, a1VAT, b1VAT, c1VAT, a1VATR, b1VATR, c1VATR, a1VATD, b1VATD, c1VATD
            FROM vw_VAT) src 
            unpivot (value FOR name IN (a1VAT, b1VAT, c1VAT, a1VATR, b1VATR, c1VATR, a1VATD, b1VATD, c1VATD)) sel
            pivot ???
```

But the pivot command I cannot get right. 
Can anybody help me?

BR, emphyrio

Comment: Please create your examples at least as text instead of pictures and if you want help faster, create an example into SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I solved the puzzle myself, using this T-SQL:

Answer (score 0):

I solved the puzzle myself, using this T-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  CASE RIGHT(name, 1) WHEN  'R' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(6), Q) + 'R' 
                            WHEN  'D' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(6), Q) + 'D' 
                            ELSE           CONVERT(nvarchar(6), Q) + 'A' END AS Q1,
        CASE RIGHT(name, 1) WHEN  'R' THEN LEFT(name, LEN(name) -1) 
                            WHEN  'D' THEN LEFT(name, LEN(name) -1) 
                            ELSE           name END AS name,  
                            value                               
FROM    (SELECT Q, a1VAT, b1VAT, c1VAT, a1VATR, b1VATR, c1VATR, a1VATD, b1VATD, c1VATD
            FROM vw_VAT) src 
            unpivot (value FOR name IN (a1VAT, b1VAT, c1VAT, a1VATR, b1VATR, c1VATR, a1VATD, b1VATD, c1VATD)) up) main
            pivot (SUM(value) FOR Q1 IN ([201501A], [201502A], [201503A], [201504A], [201501R], [201502R], [201503R], [201504R], [201501D], [201502D], [201503D], [201504D])) piv
```

Now the only thing remains is to dynamically change the IN clause of the pivot command. But that is easy now I have found the solution.

Emphyrio.